# Two UIGestureRecognizers

Tags: ios, uigesturerecognizer

I have two `UIGestureRecognizers` for a view that recognizes both simultaneously. I'd like for the finish or cancellation of the primary gesture to kill the other gesture as well. So, is there a way to kill an active gesture, i.e. force the cancellation of an active gesture recognizer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you want to kill the secondary gesture only when the primary gesture has ended or cancelled, do this in the gesture handler of the primary gesture.

```
- (void)handleGesture:(UIGestureRecognizer*)gesture {
    ...
    if ( gesture.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded || gesture.state == UIGestureRecognizerCancelled ) {
        secondaryGesture.enabled = NO;
        secondaryGesture.enabled = YES;
    }
}
```

This seems to be the only way you can cancel a gesture.

---

You can use `requireGestureRecognizerToFail:` to declare a dependency.

```
[secondaryGesture requireGestureRecognizerToFail:primaryGesture];
```

This will kill the secondary gesture on successful identification of the primary gesture. There is no such tool provided if the primary gesture is cancelled. You can probably flip the `enabled` flag of the secondary gesture to `NO` and `YES` in the gesture handler of the primary gesture on `UIGestureRecognizerStateCancelled` but that doesn't seem elegant.

Comment: Thanks for this. I don't want to kill the second gesture until the first gesture has finished, i.e. on completion (not identification) of the first gesture only.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the gestures you may want to have both. I ran up against a problem where gestures were interfering with one another and for a while had something similar to this solution. The two gestures I was trying to use was the pinch and rotate gesture. Ideally I wanted the user to be able to smoothly transition between the two without having to cancel one which I managed to achieve. I have written up [how I did it here and provided a how to video](http://www.scott-sherwood.com/?p=256) I hope this might help someone.